# how to best remove concrete splash from vinyl siding

Tags: concrete, removal

When our contractor poured the concrete for sidewalks and handicap ramp, concrete splashed onto the vinyl siding. Is there a product or way to remove this more easily than hand-scrubbing? Pressure washing did not work.

Comment: Is getting the contractor back to clean up their mess no an option?  Seems like their responsibility.

Comment: No. Unfortunately the contractor has sustained a back injury and is out of commission for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Understood, just wanted to get the obvious out of the way.  Any chance of posting a picture?  The extent of the problem might be important for certain solutions.

Comment: I will try to do so at my 1st opportunity. It'll probably be Monday. But, til then--suffice it to say it is significant on the first 12-24".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **If [the concrete] has set**, soaking the concrete with a strong
> detergent solution helps loosen its adhesion so you can scrub or
> scrape it off. Georgia-Pacific recommends mixing the following
> ingredients to make a strong cleaning solution for vinyl siding:
>
> 1/3 cup detergent 
> 2/3 cup trisodium phosphate  
> 1 gallon water
>
> Scrub with a soft-bristle brush or scrape with a plastic paint scraper. To
> give the scraper more leverage, wedge it underneath a concrete deposit
> and tap it with a hammer; this usually makes the concrete pop off.
>
> **If you have a concrete deposit that just won't budge**, muriatic acid is sure to dissolve it. If, on the other
> hand, the concrete is spread over too wide an area to make scraping,
> scrubbing or washing by hand impractical, you can opt for a pressure
> washer, but check the siding product warranty to be sure you won't
> void it by pressure-washing. Both options should be considered last
> resorts.
>
> Using Muriatic Acid
>
> Step 1 Put on goggles and rubber gloves to protect
> yourself from the corrosive effects of muriatic acid. Mix one part
> acid with three parts water in a bucket to create a 25 percent
> solution.
>
> Step 2 Test the acid solution before using it. It's safe for vinyl,
> but your siding may not be 100 percent vinyl. If it's safe, spread it
> liberally in the concrete with a natural-bristle paint brush. Don't
> use a synthetic-bristle brush -- the acid dissolves the bristles.
>
> Step 3 Allow the mixture to dissolve the concrete. It may take several
> minutes, and you may have to apply more. As the concrete dissolves,
> wash it off with a garden hose.
>
> Step 4 Clean off the residue with a kitchen scouring pad. Use the pad
> only after rinsing to avoid dissolving it in acid.
>
> https://www.hunker.com/13415205/how-to-remove-dried-concrete-from-vinyl-siding

Comment: Where does one obtain trisodium phosphate?

Comment: It's commonly available at hardware stores as a cleaning agent. Might be labeled "TSP".